# Struct convert to xml (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I received xml from javascript and parse it to the struct.

```
 struct gcrInfoStruct {
    var folderView = " "
    var actionType = " "
    var isProtocolReview = " "
    var folder: [folderDetail] = []
}
```

How could i convert this struct back to xml in order to pass to javascript?

Comment: Can you add more details? e.g. the structure of the resulting xml. Have you tried anything until now? If yes can you show us some of your code and pinpoint where exactly the problem is?

Comment: i can't find any tutorial of converting struct to xml in swift

Comment: may I ask why you communicate using xml, not JSON?

Comment: at the beginning i received xml instead of JSON.  I can't change xml to son. i am not doing a personal program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I do not know what a `folderDetail` type looks like, but let's suppose it is something like this:

```
struct folderDetail {
    var desc:String
    var value:String
}
```

I also do not know what the pattern of your XML is but let's suppose it is something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <gcrInfoStruct>
        <folderView>Folder View String</folderView>
        <actionType>Action Type String</actionType>
        <isProtocolReview>True or False</isProtocolReview>
        <folder>
            <folder1desc>folder1value</folder1desc>
            <folder2desc>folder2value</folder2desc>
        </folder>
    </gcrInfoStruct>"
```

If I'm guessing along the right lines then to generate the XML we simply need to generate a string that matches the pattern based on the struct, e.g.

```
extension gcrInfoStruct {
    func xml() -> String {
        var string = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><gcrInfoStruct><folderView>\(folderView)</folderView><actionType>\(actionType)</actionType><isProtocolReview>\(isProtocolReview)</isProtocolReview><folder>"
        for i in self.folder {
            string.appendContentsOf("<\(i.desc)>\(i.value)</\(i.desc)>")
        }
        string.appendContentsOf("</folder></gcrInfoStruct>")
        return string
    }
}
```

To implement we'd do something like this:

```
var gcr = gcrInfoStruct()
// update properties
let xml = gcr.xml()
```

But if we wanted to return XML as NSData then we'd add this additional code:

```
extension gcrInfoStruct {
    func xmlData() -> NSData? {
        return self.xml().dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
}
```

and to implement we'd do something like this:

```
var gcr = gcrInfoStruct()
// update properties
let data = gcr.xmlData()
```

It might be that the `folderDetail` is not simply a pair of strings or that the XML pattern varies but hopefully there is enough here to get you started.